# Hide nested html table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a nested table column like:

[image]

Now I want to hide mark columns by table column index. How is it possible? Please provide concept not solution. I have confused how to start my task.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 20%;">Customer Name</th>
      <th style="width: 20%;">Location</th>
      <th style="width: 40%;">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="width: 50%;">Order No</th>
              <th style="width: 50%;">Date</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th style="width: 20%;">No Of Order</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="cutomer in gridData">
      <td style="width: 20%;">{{ cutomer.itemName }}</td>
      <td style="width: 20%;">{{ cutomer.itemName }}</td>
      <td style="width: 40%;">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
          <tbody>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="customerOrder in cutomer.orderList">
              <th style="width: 50%;">{{ customerOrder.orderNo }}</th>
              <th style="width: 50%;">{{ customerOrder.date }}</th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 20%;">No Of Order</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: SO is about getting solutions. You are supposed to define what exactly you want and describe and show your best attempt so far and how it fails.

Comment: I want to hide table column according to runtime settings. In this case I will use a directive to hide table column.

Comment: Do you know the child table index?

Comment: If I use child table index how do I start working? Provide full concept.

Comment: Could you please show the final (albeit minimal/"[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)," and *tidied*) HTML that's produced by whatever templating system you're using, rather than the template itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function show_hide_column(col_no, do_show) {
   var tbl = document.getElementById('id_of_table');
   var col = tbl.getElementsByTagName('col')[col_no];
   if (col) {
     col.style.visibility=do_show?"":"collapse";
   }
}
```

Comment: You are right for simple table. But I need to hide nested table columns.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272211/align-nested-table-headers-using-jquery and refer this http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/34934-hide-row-depends-on-nested-table-results/

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use javascript to hide columns you want to hide.
But you need some event to hide and show columns you need.
Below i have added a class `x` to the table that contains your columns to be hidden.

```
<head>
    <style>
        .x
        {
            display:none;
        }   
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 20%;">Customer Name</th>
            <th style="width: 20%;">Location</th>
            <th style="width: 40%;">
                <table class="table x table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th  style="width: 50%;">Order No</th>
                            <th  style="width: 50%;">Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 20%;">No Of Order</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="cutomer in gridData">
            <td style="width: 20%;">1</td>
            <td style="width: 20%;">1</td>
            <td style="width: 40%;">
                <table class="table x table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr data-ng-repeat="customerOrder in cutomer.orderList">
                            <th style="width: 50%;">1</th>
                            <th style="width: 50%;">1</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 20%;">No Of Order</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now if you want to toggle between hide and show you can do it by changing css through javascript(this part is optional if you want),but for that you require a event or you can do it document.ready method too.
for example
I suppose you have a button having `id='slidingcolumns'`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slidingcolumns').click(function(){
        $(".x").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

I hope this might help you
good luck

Answer (score 0):

Here is the 'concept' only to hide the column using index like you asked:

1. To hide the column by index, you could use CSS with :nth-child pseudo class. For example: td:nth-child(5). #5 would be which ever index you want to use. Please see this link for more details/explanation if you haven't used nth-child before: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child (I recommend looking at the example how to "select the third child element of the second element".
2. If you want to hide the column by index with a trigger event, I would use the javascript approach that Rudra has mentioned. For example, add a class to the html tag you wish to hide and blind it with an  event to do the hiding, or alternatively you could bind it to an id.